# python print matrix in spiral using boolean values

Tags: python

I'm looking to print a matrix in spiral way but I'm having some issues understanding when/how exactly to change the boolean values to make it work. This is what I have till now:

A 4x5 matrix

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]
```

and the function that should print it

> ```
> def print_spiral(matrix):
>     left = False
>     right = True
>     down = False
>     up = False
>     min_x = 0
>     max_x = len(matrix) -1 
>     min_y = 0
>     max_y = len (matrix[0]) - 1 
>     x,y = 0, 0
>     while True:
>         print matrix[x][y]
>         if y < max_y and x == min_x:
>             y=y+1
>         elif y == max_y and x < max_x:
>             x=x+1
>         elif x == max_x and y > min_y:
>             right = False
>             y=y-1
>         elif y == min_y and x > min_x:
>             x = x-1
> ```

As it is now, is not printing the matrix in a spiral way but is going in a loop printing the outside rows and columns of the matrix. I'm trying to solve this problem by making use of the boolean left, right, up , down variables but I'm stuck with the logic at this point. Any advices please?!

Comment: What do you mean by "print in a spiral way"?

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and expected output?

Comment: @RPGillespie is exactly like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726756/print-two-dimensional-array-in-spiral-order but different way of doing it

Comment: @mgilson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726756/print-two-dimensional-array-in-spiral-order